# Difference between SimpleBindings vs ScriptEngine.createBindings() (Graal and Nashhorn)

Tags: java, nashorn, graalvm, scriptengine, graaljs

Note, I use both Nashhorn and Graal, so it's possible that the `ScriptEngine` used below is an instance of [GraalJSScriptEngine](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/scriptengine/GraalJSScriptEngine.java) or the nashhorn engine.

When I call `createBindings` using the [GraalJSScriptEngine](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/scriptengine/GraalJSScriptEngine.java) engine:

```
Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.createBindings();
```

it returns a [GraalJSBindings](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/scriptengine/GraalJSBindings.java) object, which has a `close` function which closes the context associated with the bindings:

```
@Override
public void close() {
    if (context != null) {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

In my application, I had to make sure to close this context after each use, via `GraalJSBindings.close()`, this was to prevent a memory leak in which the contexts were not getting GC'ed. For example:

```
// Create bindings
Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.createBindings();

// Do stuff
...

// Close bindings if they implement AutoClosable
// I also use the Nashhorn engine, so its possible that bindings
// may not be an instance of AutoCloseable/GraalJSBindings
if (bindings instanceof AutoCloseable) {
    try {
        ((AutoCloseable) bindings ).close();
    } catch (final RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to close script bindings and associated context", ex);
    }
}
```

I noticed there is another way to create bindings, not via the engine, but by explicitly instantiating a `SimpleBindings` object. I am wondering what the difference is in the following, i.e. could I simple just replace `scriptEngine.createBindings()` with `new SimpleBindings()` and avoid having to close the bindings like I am doing above? Or is there some advantage to using `scriptEngine.createBindings()`?

```
Bindings bindings = graalJSScriptEngine.createBindings();

vs

Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
```

Answer (score 1):

internally, `SimpleBindings` are wrapped in a `GraalJSBindings` object. So effectively, the behaviour should be identical.

The performance of `GraalJSBindings` might be better though, especially if you repeatedly `eval` code for the same bindings. And `GraalJSBindings` allows to manipulate the bindings while they are evaluated (from a different thread).

Best,
Christian